# Is there no commandline options for odbcad32.exe?

Tags: odbc, dsn

I want to create a DSN, using odbcad32.exe (32-bit), from the commandline. But when I execute "odbcad32 /?", it is displaying the window to create the DSN manually. The commandline facility is available for odbcconf (64-bit version), but I need it for 32-bit and I cannot use GUI to create because I need to automate this. Any help..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the command line, populate the ODBC registry directly. You will find that it is very easy to do. Just have a look at HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI (for system DSN), or HKCU\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI

Please note that on 64-bit machines the node will be under SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC

Comment: If I do this, how do I save SQL creds/passwords?

Answer (score 0):

the command is [`odbcconf.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388579(v=vs.85).aspx) despite may be it's more easy to use directly the registry.Here's an [example](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6184)